# Ubuntu 16.04 recognizes external mic, but programs don't. How to fix?

Tags: sound, microphone

Previously, I could normally record voice using Gnome Sound Recorder (GSR) version 3.18.2-1. Now, I can no longer do it. Although Ubuntu does recognize the mic, GSR doesn't record anything.

In the image below, the sound settings window is on top and GSR's window is at the bottom. It can be seen that while Ubuntu's sound sensor detects sounds from the mic (the orange bars move in response to the sound capture), GSR's sound sensor doesn't (the cyan line remains flat) and nothing is recorded.

[image]

Notice that although Ubuntu is able to detect the sound capture, it needs human intervention to begin to do it.  Once I boot in, Ubuntu's sound sensor is all grayed out:

[image]

I need to manually move a bit the mic plug into the mic jack of the PC for Ubuntu to detect the mic, but as shown above, applications still don't get access to it.

If I dual boot into Windows, everything works perfectly. So, I can't figure out why Ubuntu is detecting the sound, but applications don't have access to it. And this occurred overnight. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I had the same problem, and I fixed it by these steps: (1) install GNOME Alsa Mixer. Hit a checkbox to unmute something. (2) This step also muted the microphone, unmute it in the audio settings.

Comment: Can gnome-alsamixer be installed without interfering with pulseaudio?